How to decode GIAI-96 data with postgres?
Is there a postgres plugin to help decode EPC hex strings read from RFID tags to "Company Prefix" and "Individual Asset Reference"?

implemented following
https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/epc/tds_1_1_rev_1_27-standard-20050510.pdf
Page 52 -  3.8.2.2 GIAI-96 Decoding Procedure
You can define two functions as below:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_company_prefix_from_giai_tag_bitarray(bitarray bit(96)) 
RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE
    partition_value int;
    res bigint;
BEGIN
    partition_value=SUBSTRING(bitarray, 96-84, 3)::bit(3)::int;
    res:=-1;
    case 
        when partition_value=0 
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,15,40)::bit(40)::bigint::text,12,'0');
        when partition_value=1
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,15,37)::bit(37)::bigint::text,11,'0');
        when partition_value=2
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,15,34)::bit(34)::bigint::text,10,'0');
        when partition_value=3
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,15,30)::bit(30)::bigint::text,9,'0');
        when partition_value=4
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,15,27)::bit(27)::bigint::text,8,'0');
        when partition_value=5
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,15,24)::bit(24)::bigint::text,7,'0');
        when partition_value=6
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,15,20)::bit(20)::bigint::text,6,'0');
        ELSE res:=-1;
    end CASE;
    RETURN res;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

and
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_iar_from_giai_tag_bitarray(bitarray bit(96)) RETURNS text AS
$$
DECLARE
    partition_value int;
    res bigint;
BEGIN
    partition_value=SUBSTRING(bitarray, 96-84, 3)::bit(3)::int;
    res:=-1;
    case 
        when partition_value=0 
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,55,42)::bit(41)::bigint::text,12,'0');
        when partition_value=1
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,52,45)::bit(45)::bigint::text,13,'0');
        when partition_value=2
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,49,48)::bit(48)::bigint::text,14,'0');
        when partition_value=3
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,45,52)::bit(52)::bigint::text,15,'0');
        when partition_value=4
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,42,55)::bit(55)::bigint::text,16,'0');
        when partition_value=5
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,39,58)::bit(58)::bigint::text,17,'0');
        when partition_value=6
            then res := lpad(SUBSTRING(bitarray,35,62)::bit(62)::bigint::text,18,'0');
        ELSE res:=-1;
    end CASE;
    RETURN res;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

And then test them like
SELECT extract_company_prefix_from_giai_tag_bitarray(('x' ||'342EBCF6CBA00140DA26C142')::bit(96))

and
SELECT extract_iar_from_giai_tag_bitarray(('x' ||'342EBCF6CBA00140DA26C142')::bit(96))

And ultimately get them to work on a table query.
SELECT extract_company_prefix_from_giai_tag_bitarray(('x' || tag_content)::bit(96)) from read_tags;

and
SELECT extract_iar_from_giai_tag_bitarray(('x' || tag_content)::bit(96)) from read_tags;

